# Compare datetime values with microseconds in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a date time value which is coming from the database. The value will be a date time with  microseconds like `2014-03-18 10:34:10.938`. Now i have to compare it with a same value which is also a  microseconds date time value from the database. I have tried with `strtotime` but it is not considering the microseconds value.

So anybody can suggest a way to compare these values.

I tried the following:

```
$val1 = '2014-03-18 10:34:10.938';
$val1 = '2014-03-18 10:34:10.800';

if(strtotime($val1) > strtotime($val2))
  //some code
else
  //some code
```

Also i tried without using the `strtotime`

```
$val1 = '2014-03-18 10:34:10.938';
$val1 = '2014-03-18 10:34:10.800';

if($val1 > $val2)
  //some code
else
  //some code
```

Method 2 get successes.So my question is am i using the correct way.?

**EDIT**

As per duplicate marking by @showdev i have tried the following

```
$val1 = '2014-03-18 10:34:09.999';
$val2 = '2014-03-18 10:34:09.940';

if(new DateTime($val1) > new DateTime($val2))
  echo "1 is bigger";
else
  echo "2 is bigger";
//Always output 2 is bigger unless i change $val1 seconds value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Example #2 of the DateTime::diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) documentation, you should be able to use comparison operators on the `DateTime` object. However, it doesn't seem to account for microseconds.

E.g. if you do

```
$val1 = '2014-03-18 10:34:09.939';
$val2 = '2014-03-18 10:34:09.940';

$datetime1 = new DateTime($val1);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($val2);
var_dump($datetime1->diff($datetime2));
```

You get the following, which doesn't show "u" (microtime):

```
object(DateInterval)#3 (15) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(0)
  ["d"]=>
  int(0)
  ["h"]=>
  int(0)
  ["i"]=>
  int(0)
  ["s"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday_behavior"]=>
  int(0)
  ["first_last_day_of"]=>
  int(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(0)
  ["days"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_type"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_amount"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_weekday_relative"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_special_relative"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Here is a workaround that works for me:

```
$val1 = '2014-03-18 10:34:09.999';
$val2 = '2014-03-18 10:34:09.940';
$datetime1 = new DateTime($val1);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($val2);

if($datetime1 > $datetime2)
  echo "1 is bigger";
else if ($datetime1->format('u') > $datetime2->format('u'))
  echo "1 is bigger";
else
  echo "2 is bigger";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a string compare instead of date compare, however for this type of format string compare will work just fine. 
If you want, you might want to experiment with pulling data from database in a different format, ex:

```
select concat(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time), MICROSECOND(time)) from table.db;
```

this will convert your date into microseconds, and will make your sql server do date conversion for you.

Comment: Can you complete your answer

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php example #2 says you should be able to do a comparision like OP has, but `DateTime` doesn't seem to be accounting for microtime